Too many export buttons how can i manage this?

I need to adjust this all export buttons it doesnt fit like this.
Below the buttons it consists data tables.

Can you [edit] the question to give it more context? What are these buttons used for? Why can't these be checkboxes instead? What does the rest of the screen or flow look like?

Welcome to the site! We can help more if you tell us about (1) the process your users want to complete and (2) what your specific concerns are. In your case, I infer this is a table toolbar. Are there any other buttons? Why is PDF marked differently? What is the relative frequency the actions are used? What do you mean by "doesn't fit" (the fact that two rows are needed with a certain resolution and language choice)? Did you try any other designs, and if so, why did you favor this one? Have you tried to find similar questions on this site?

You can put in your export buttons inside the dropdown so when you select an export type, you get to see screen 2 that allows you to select the export format. hope this helps. Cheers.



There's no reason you need to have each export as a separate button. A much simpler way to do is is via a separate dialog.
Delete all the export buttons except one, rename it to 'Export...' and then display an export dialog, similar to this. Then have a dropdown or other selection option in there for selecting the file format.

